# pass model to action using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass Model to the controller action using jquery

Here is my controller action code

```
[HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult AddUserStatus(NewBlogPostModel model)
        {
            //code goes here
        }
```

Here is my view code

```
@model Platform3.Models.ViewModels.NewBlogPostModel

<div class="pull-left">
    <div class="editor-field" >        
        <textarea class="form-control" style="resize: none;" rows="4" cols="80" maxlength="200" id="user-status" placeholder="What's in your mind?"></textarea>
        <div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Update Status" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: -15px;">
    </div>
</div>
$("#submit-button").click(function () {        
            var status = $('#user-status').val();
            // I want to assign status to Model.Body;
            // Call Create action method
            // I want to pass the model to the action here
            $.post('/Partial/AddUserStatus', { model:  Model});
    });
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Json.Encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) Method converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //Convert Model to JSON 
$.post('/Partial/AddUserStatus', model);
```

Comment: thank you @Satpal it helped me a lot now i can assign whatever i want to this JSON object and send it to my action :) ;)